# Are large HTTP envelopes split across several partial http requests?

Tags: http

I'm reading a [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) that looks at different web service architectures, including an overview of how the SOAP protocol can be implemented in via HTTP. This was interesting to me because I do a lot of WCF development and didn't realize how client/server communication was implemented.

Since protocols like TCP and whatever is lower than that have fixed maximum packet sizes and as such have to split messages into packets, I just assumed that HTTP was similar. Is that not the case?

I.e. If I make a GET/POST request with a 20MB body, will a single HTTP envelope be sent and reassembled on the server?

If this is the case, what is the largest practical size of an http request? i have previously configured Nginx servers to allow 20mb file transfers and I'm wondering if this is too high...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HTTP specification point of view, there is no limit for HTTP payload. According to [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3):

> Any Content-Length field value greater than or equal to zero is valid.  Since there is no predefined limit to the length of a payload, a recipient MUST anticipate potentially large decimal numerals and prevent parsing errors due to integer conversion overflows.

However, to prevent attack via very long or very slow stream of data, a web server may reject such HTTP request and return `413 Payload Too Large` response.

*"Since protocols like TCP and whatever is lower than that have fixed maximum packet sizes and as such have to split messages into packets, I just assumed that HTTP was similar. Is that not the case?"*

No. HTTP is an application level protocol and is totally different. As HTTP is based on TCP, when the data is transferring, it would automatically split into packets on TCP level. There is no need to split the request on HTTP level.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP body can be as large as you want it to be, there is no download size limit, the size limit is usually set for uploads, to prevent someone uploading massive files to your server.

You can ask for a section of a resource using the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) header, if you only want part of it.

IE had limits of 2 and 4 GB at times, but these have been fixed since. [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/298618/you-cannot-download-files-that-are-2-gb-or-larger)

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know about the 'Range' header